# Send Message to all Friends Discord.py (User Token)

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

How would I go about sending a Message to all my friends? I'm hoping to be able to achieve this with the Discord.py library, hopefully someone here knows.
Please note that i want to access my friend list using my token, this is not a bot.
I do this because i want to automate my dms to answer some everyday questions.

I currently get this Error:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Program:

```
import discord

with open('TOKEN_TESTUSER.txt', 'r') as f:
    TOKEN = f.readline()

client = discord.client()

@client.event
async def on_connect():
    for user in client.user.friends:
        try:
            await user.send('Message')
            print("Working")
            
        except:
            print("Not working")

client.run(TOKEN, bot=False)
```

I really appreciate any answer.

Comment: Could you share the full Traceback you get?

Comment: @yeti
Here is the full Traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\xianc\Desktop\CHRIS\Discord Bots\Botted Accounts\FriendList.py", line 6, in <module>
    client = discord.client()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: It's `Client` with a capital C...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discord removed this feature when migrating to version 2.0.
You can see a list of the changes [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html?highlight=friends#).

Unfortunately, I think you can no longer message your friends on discord with a bot. :(